# Scroll after ckick banner into iframe

Tags: javascript

I have a web site with banner that load into iframe on the top of the page. In the bottom of the same page i have a div with id. Some people click on the banner into iframe. I want people who click on the banner to scroll down the page to div. Thanks!

Comment: Add some code that you have tried

Comment: `$(function() {
    var scrollToAnchor = function() {
        var elem = $("#tabs_video");
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: elem.offset().top
        }, 1000 );
    };
    // bind to click event
     $(".js-scroll").click(function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            scrollToAnchor();
    });
});`